# Mod_rewrite character mystery

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm slowly learning mod_rewrite (keyword is slowly) and am using a tutorial's line of code but I'm stumped as to what one of the symbols in the line mean.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^home|^about
```

What do the ^ characters mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache Regular Expression (or regexp for short) is known as a *Perl Compatible Regular Expression* (PCRE) engine.  If you search the web for PCRE tutorial, you will find hundreds of hits

The ^ character anchors the string to the start of the expression so this means beginning with home or about.

Comment: Thanks and I'll keep note to search for PCRE tutorials next time.

Comment: If you use PHP, then the PHP help on and offline includes a reference guide.  I'd give you a few links, but my problem is that I learnt Perl before there was an Internet, and I only use references for the esoteric regexp stuff now. I did the google search for "PCRE regular expression tutorial and there were  a lot of useful hits :-)  Have a look at the regexp checker on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153262/tips-for-debugging-htaccess-rewrite-rules